# button button xml will not apply to background

Tags: android, xml, android-button

I have created a custom button xml file for button pressed and non pressed background colors. Colors are inside color xml file. When I try to apply the custom_button to the background option in the xml editor the file comes up but I am unable to click to apply. I have done this same procedure but used an Toggle button on last project. My app will need 10 buttons when 1 is pressed then the other 9 will reset to unpressed state which is done by code.  I will also need the option to press each of the buttons to stay pressed and not reset so the reset function will not be called.  Any suggestions to do both options with buttons or toggle buttons ?

custom_button.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/button_back" 
    android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/button_back_selected"/>

 </selector>
```

color.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<color name="button_back">#901E78</color>
<color name="button_back_selected">#FF1E00</color>

</resources>
```

Reset code

```
      private void ResetAllFixtureButtons() {
    Fixture1.setPressed(false);
    Fixture2.setPressed(false);
    Fixture3.setPressed(false);
    Fixture4.setPressed(false);
    Fixture5.setPressed(false);
    Fixture6.setPressed(false);
    Fixture7.setPressed(false);
    Fixture8.setPressed(false);
    Fixture9.setPressed(false);
    Fixture10.setPressed(false);

}
```

I resolved the issue by adding the custom button to the xml file and changing the button to toggle buttons. I also changed the fixture reset to Fixture1.setChecked(false);

cutom.xml

```
     <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:textSize="30dp" android:textOff="F1" android:textOn="F1"         
    android:background="@drawable/custom" android:textColor="@drawable/white"/>
```

Comment: Aside from your questions, are you sure your items in `custom_button.xml` are not swapped?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If the android:state_selected="true"it would just show pressed and not pressed color. I am not sure why I cannot apply to background option.